# fetch single model from json array in backbone.js

Tags: arrays, json, backbone.js, model, fetch

I'm very new to Backbone so I may be missing something obvious. However, I've searched stackoverflow and haven't found anything that fits my issue.

My model just has the urlRoot:

```
Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/data/album.json'
});
```

The json looks something like this:

```
[{
  "id": "01",
  "title": "title1",
  "artist": "artist1",
  "tracks": [{
    "track": "track1",
    "url": "/music/101.mp3"
  },
  {
    "track": "track2",
    "url": "/music/102.mp3"
  }]
},
{
  "id": "02",
  "title": "title2",
  "artist": "artist2",
  "tracks": [{
    "track": "track1",
    "url": "/music/201.mp3"
  },
  {
    "track": "track2",
    "url": "/music/202.mp3"
  }]
}]
```

I'm able to fetch the objects in the array:

```
album = new Album();
album.fetch();
album.toJSON(); --> //Object {0: Object, 1: Object}
```

Calling toJSON on my new model shows that the array fetched correctly. If I expand each object I see all the attributes.

However, when I try to fetch just a single object from the array it doesn't work.

```
album = new Album({id: 01});
album.fetch()
album.toJSON(); --> // Object {id: 1}
```

What am I missing?

---

Comment: Have you configured your backend API to respond to routes like `/data/album/1.json` ?

Comment: did you managed this issue?

Comment: yes, both comments pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to change a few things in you code and read more about [`Backbone.Model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) and [`Backbone.Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) and how REST-ful resources behave themselves.

---

Try to use `Backbone.Collection` when you are dealing with the collections of objects or so called resources (from REST). And mention appropriate `Backbone.Model` to that collection which will represent the single item in your collection. In your case `/data/album` is resource.

---

To demonstrate it let's change your example to the following (I will use routes without `json` extension):

```
var Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/data/album', 
    // mention here defaults hash, add parse method if you need to change response
    // from backend, add validations, add idAttribute if the name of 
    // unique identifier is not the id 
});

var Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/data/album', 
    model: Album
});

var albums = new Albums();
albums.fetch();
```

Now you have collection of `Backbone.Model`s which is better to manipulate and use in Backbone's approach. You can do anything you want with it using mixed `UnderscoreJS` methods - filter, sort, search for the model with id and so on.

Whenever you need to fetch the single model or the single item of your resource you need to understand how `Backbone.Model` will change the route (urlRoot).

When you doing this:

```
var album = new Album({id: 1});
var album.fetch();
```

It will trigger request to the following route `GET '/data/album/1'` in your case `GET '/data/album.json/1'`.

---

**You have a few options to fix your issue:**

1. Change backend API to respond to routes without `json` extension and for the single item handle routes like `/data/album/id`
2. Rewrite the way `Backbone.Model` concatenate the id to the url. You can rewrite the [`url`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-69) function of `Backbone.Model` to support routes with extensions.
3. If you cannot touch the backend (the worst way) you can preserve your old implentetion and add a few workarounds like adding the `parse` method to the `Backbone.Model` .... actually it will start to behave like a Backbone.Collection, because any time you need single item you need to fetch all the things and find the needed object in that mess.

So I suggest you to try the mix of 1st and 2nd options.